# Magento 1.9 Website loading super slow

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, server-setup

My website is loading very slow, I am facing this issue since quite a long time. Suddenly all works properly and then suddenly website loading time goes to 30-40 seconds. quick fix is that if I Truncate core_url_rewrite db, the website starts opening in normal speed like 3-4 seconds, but some of the pages doesn't work so for them to work I need to reindex catalog url rewrite, then again it will start working slow. I hardly have 15 mb of core_url_rewrite db size. My total products on website is 5-6k. This issue suddenly started happening after we planned to upgrade to Magento 2 and the developer who was working on this had already finished the pre-migration process and left the project in half way. Due to his migrations there are some M2 tables created in our live database. We also upgraded our server to 8GB ram , 240 Gb HDD & 8 CPUS. Still this issue didnt resolve. Please if anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: `the website starts opening in normal speed like 3-4 seconds` ... normal is 500ms

Comment: start from checking profiler. when slow load use database monitoring or strace php process. or you can use `newrelic`

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: For now we have switched the sever and all looks fine. Thanks for the info

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my proflle, Network profile where we have downloadable FREE utility scripts, tips and contact information.